# Connecting Integration runtime to azure data factory and purview

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-purview

I want to use azure data factory to load data from my on-prem server to azure, and I would also scan my on-prem server using purview.

How can I scan the same server using one integration rutine and not manually changing it every time?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you can only share self-hosted integration runtimes between multiple data factories, not between data factory and Purview (or Synapse). There is a feature request for the ADF/Synapse sharing option currently open: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/307516-azure-synapse-analytics/suggestions/41026642-allow-to-share-a-self-hosted-ir-from-data-factory

Comment: Does this mean there's no way to have 2 Synapse workspaces share a single self-hosted integration runtime?

Comment: No, there is no "sharing" tab available for the integration runtime setup in Synapse (unlike in ADF).

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear. From what i understood, you need a Self hosted Integration runtime, (refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime)) to connect to on-premise network/servers. Once you create it, you can use that IR to create required Linked services.

Comment: The problem is that you can use it only for purview or for data factory, but you cannot share the IR between resources, and you cannot have more than one per server. I am trying to understand how to do it, without changing it manually.

Comment: You could share IRs between Resources https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/sharing-a-self-hosted-integration-runtime-infrastructure-with-multiple-data-factories/?cdn=disable

Comment: You can share it between multiple data factories, but not different resources. I need to share it with purview